# How to reset selected rows in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a small rshiny app, in which i can select row in datatable and get values from first columns.

but how to quickly get rid of the selected rows and values without clicking on the row again?

also if you know what can be improved in this code, then write, I just started coding in R

```
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput('main_information'),
  fluidRow(
    column(8,verbatimTextOutput('selected_rows', placeholder = TRUE)),
    fluidRow(
      column(4,actionButton("reset", "RESET"))
    )
  )
)

# Define server function
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  getScoreTable<-reactive({
    db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "path")
    data <- dbGetQuery(
      conn = db,
      statement = 
        '...'
    )
  })
  
  output$main_information <- renderDataTable(
    getScoreTable(),
    options = list(
      pageLength = 5,
      lengthMenu = list(c(5,10, 25, 50, 100), 
                        c('5', '10', '25','50', '100'))
    )
  )
  
  s<-reactiveValues(data= NULL)
  
  output$selected_rows = renderPrint({
    s = input$main_information_rows_selected
    if (length(s)) {
      cat('These values were selected:\n\n')
      cat(getScoreTable()[s,1], sep = '\n')
    }else{
      cat('No value has been selected')
    }
  })
  
  
}

# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom action button:

```r
library(DT)

js <- "
function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
  dt.rows().deselect();
}
"

datatable(
  iris,
  extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"),
  selection = "none",
  options = list(
    "dom"     = "Bfrtip",
    "select"  = TRUE,
    "buttons" = list(
      list(
        "extend" = "collection",
        "text"   = "DESELECT",
        "action" = JS(js)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

This example works fine. If you have an issue in Shiny, please provide a minimal reproducible code, not using SQL.